# SharePoint 2013 (Welcome Page) Search People missing from Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, people-search

I want to create a Employee Directory then i followed some link to do it.

I am trying to add the (Welcome Page) Search People from Page layout but i can't find it.

All required features were already activated but i still can't find it.
I am using SharePoint 2013.

Hope Someone could help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you go to the Site Setting > Page layouts and site templates and add those layouts to your preferred site ?

[image]

However, the Search People layout is just come with search. You can use any page layout and drop the Search box, refinement, result, and configure them by yourself.